# Disable only one of two connected iSight cameras?

Tags: macos, drivers, isight

I have two Apple TB displays connected to my laptop, ant I'm running into all kinds of problems having both iSight cameras detected. Is there any way to selectively disable just one of the cameras? I'm aware of the kext removal trick, but I assume that would just disable all cameras using that driver and not just one of them.

Am I out of luck? Are there any third-party utilities that let you disable connected hardware (a la Windows' Device Manager)?